# Displaying ${} of record from jsp to jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

```
<c:forEach var = "student" items="${result}">
<tr>
<th>${student.name}</th>
<th><a href ="display.jsp ">Notify</a></th>
</tr>   
</c:forEach>
```

This is my output.jsp. Notice that I've put a link "Notify" to forward it on display.jsp. But I'm not sure how to display a record of student.name onto my display.jsp 's textbox. Thanks

Comment: if I understand it right, you're directly doing a jsp-jsp forward, I don't think that's a good way to do it. Change your href to point to some action that will forward to display.jsp, that way display.jsp is completely invisible from the client :)

Comment: are you trying to access currently selected `student.name` for which you click Notify in your display.jsp ?

Comment: If not sensitive, you can send student name along with url as parameter or you can set it to a proper scope.

Comment: By click Notify on my output.jsp, it will direct me to display.jsp which student.name will be appear in my <input type="textbox">.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the student name over to the display.jsp (e.g. using a GET parameter).

Modify your link as follows:

```
<th><a href ="display.jsp?studentName=${student.name} ">Notify</a></th>
```

Inside your display.jsp your textbox may look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="studentName" value="${param['studentName']}" />
```